# Problems dynamically printing table using PHP from database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am working on a project were I am taking input from the user for a range of dates and then printing out the results between those two dates. Currently, I am having no problems getting the data from the database and having them print. The issue is with the formatting and structure of the table.

Currently the table is printing the titles of the table each time a result is being printed and I am having issues changing that.

The code provided is what I have been using.

This is for a class so please try to explain what needs to be done instead of simply giving me code!

```
<form method="post" action="index.php">
Date Range From:
<input type="text" id="dateFrom" name="dateFrom" value="">
To:
<input type="text" id="dateTo" name="dateTo" value="">
<input type="submit" id="submit">
</form>

<?php
include('../inclass/db_connect.php');

if(isset($_POST['dateFrom'])){$dateFrom =   $_POST['dateFrom'];}else{$dateFrom=0;};
if(isset($_POST['dateTo'])){$dateTo = $_POST['dateTo'];}else{$dateTo=0;};

$result =$pdo->prepare("SELECT matchDate, player1, player2, result, eco FROM    matches WHERE matchDate BETWEEN :a AND :b LIMIT 250");
$result->bindParam(':a', $dateFrom);
$result->bindParam(':b', $dateTo);
$result->execute();

for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++){
?>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Match Date</th>
        <th>Player 1</th>
        <th>Player 2</th>
        <th>Result</th>
        <th>ECO Code</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['matchDate']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['player1']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['player2']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['result']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['eco']; ?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<?php
}
?>
```

http://cps276.net/zgambrell/04/index.php

Comment: can you tell a valid date range so that we can check your link?

Comment: 2000/06/06 - 2001/06/06

Comment: I guess I needed to be just a little more specific... I need the table headers to also be pulled up dynamically. Instead of having them always sitting on the page, I am trying to also have them pulled up with the data when the user inputs the dates. Is there any way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You should move the table and table header out of the loop or you would end up adding them for each row returned by the query. The code should roughly look like the following :

```
<table>
  <!-- table header --> 
  <tr>
    <th>..</th>
    ..
  </tr>

  <!-- Records -->
  <?php
  for (?;?;?) {
  ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['?'] ?></td>
    ..
  </tr>
  <?php } ?>
<!-- End of table --> 
</table>
```

Comment: When i move the table headers outside of the loop, it only puts the first loop through into the table, the other data records are not being processed and put into the correct row and column in the table. Do you know of anyway I can have it so all of the data gets formatted into the table?

Comment: Looks like you are either not enclosing the php script properly or they are misplaced. I tried running php script from the link with a date range and looking at source thus generated, it seems closing table tag is placed inside the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

> Table html code is within the ForEach loop. That's why it is printing for each record. Place the table colum header outside the for loop.

```
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Match Date</th>
            <th>Player 1</th>
            <th>Player 2</th>
            <th>Result</th>
            <th>ECO Code</th>
        </tr>

    for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++){
    ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['matchDate']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['player1']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['player2']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['result']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['eco']; ?></td>
        </tr>

    <?php
    }
    ?>
</table>
```